# Element 'CrystalReportSource' is not a known element

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I faced this problem while downgrade my application to crystal report 10 from 11
any one have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to remove the element CrystalReportSource as it does not exist in crystal report Viewer 10.

This can also be caused becuse you have many crystal reports versions on your PC.
so the TagPrefix="CR" is not unique.
Clear your project's refrence, just keep one version of crystal reports.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay but after removing it what should I use what is the substitute. and regarding the versions i had removed all old version and install only CR10

Comment: @Mohamed, is "Element 'CrystalReportSource' is not a known element" an actually error, or just highlighted in green in VS?

Comment: it is an error  - Error 64 The type or namespace name 'CrystalReportSource' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)